# select column which contains other columns , SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE Column2
```

for strings I have no problems :

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%word%'
```

how to use it for columns?

Lets say that Column1 = `'Hello World'`, and Column2 = `'Hello'`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like below for sql server

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%'+Column2+'%'
```

or use concat which support most dbms

```
  WHERE Column1  LIKE CONCAT('%',Column2, '%')
```

|| use as concat in oracle and this ansi standard

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%'||Column2||'%'
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Oracle, is taht fastest way to do that? i have milions of lines?

Comment: `||` is also the ANSI SQL way to concatenate!

Comment: thank you, `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Column1 LIKE '%'||Column2||'%' ` works for me , is that fastest way to do that, or i can improve speed somehow?